# Can Access Website using IP address on a Network but Not Using Host Name

Tags: iis-7, dns, self-hosting

I am hosting a website on the intranet. I configured the hosts file in etc folder and added the following:-

```
10.XXX.42.67    GSOnlinePortal.com
```

In IIS7 i have added my website and this is how my Site Binding looks like:

[image]

Now when i access this website on the host machine using http://GSOnlineportal.com, it works just fine. **But i cannot access it through a different (remote) computer on a network.**

If i change my binding on the IIS to look like this:-

[image]

Now i can access this website both on the host machine and a remote machine on network using `http://10.XXX.42.67/` without any problems.

**What is want is to access the website on remote machine on a network using http://GSOnlinePortal.com. Please help. I am fairly new and have finally come close to achieving this. Will highly appreciate it. Thank you.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The local etc/hosts file is used to provide domain name resolution services to the local system. The remote system from which you are trying to open the website is unaware of this mapping and cannot resolve the name GSOnlinePortal.com to IP 10.XXX.42.67. Two solutions are available for your problem:

1. If you have a DNS server available in your network, you could register the name there. (Recommended)
2. You could add the mapping in the hosts file of every system you want to access the web site.

Comment: Thank you. That explains it. Thanks.